# Is AWS ec2 instance dhcp enabled?

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, dhcp

I want to know if my instance is dhcp enabled or not. If DHCP is enabled then I want to disable it. Please help me.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions only

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  Most of us here are happy to help you improve your craft, but are less happy acting as short-order unpaid programming staff. Show us your work so far as a [mcve], the result you were expecting and the results you got, and we'll help you figure it out. It may help to re-read [ask].

Comment: _WHY_ do you wish to disable DHCP?

Answer (score 2):

Amazon EC2 allocates private IP addresses via DHCP. You **must** use DHCP to receive the IP addresses.

You could certainly disable DHCP within the operating system, but it might not behave correctly within the Amazon VPC network.